# React this.props.match is undefined

Tags: reactjs

This should be an easy one. How do I access props.match from within a React component class? Line 17 below contains the culprit.

Edit: I am trying to access the ID parameter from the URL.
Edit again to add more relevant code

I don't believe the `withRouter` solution is available in the latest version of react-router-dom...

Also, `useParams` is not usable in a class component...

post-detail.js, see line 17

```
  5 class Post extends React.Component {
  6     constructor(props) {
  7         super(props);
  8         this.state = {
  9             title: '',
 10             content: ''
 11         };
 12     }
 13
 14     componentDidMount() {
 15         let api = new Api();
 16
 17         api.posts(this.props.match.params.id).then(data => {
 18             this.setState({
 19                 title: data.title.rendered,
 20                 content: data.content.rendered
 21             });
 22         });
 23     }
 24
 25     render() {
 26         let post = this.state;
 27         return (
 28             <div className='row'>
 29                 <h3>{post.title}</h3>
 30                 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.content}} />
 31             </div>
 32         );
 33     }
 34 }
 35
 36 export {Post};
```

app.js, see line 27

```
 10 class App extends React.Component {
 11
 12     constructor() {
 13         super();
 14         this.state = {
 15             posts: []
 16         };
 17     }
 18
 19     componentDidMount() {}
 20
 21     render() {
 22         return (
 23             <div className="container">
 24                 <h1>hello world</h1>
 25                 <Routes>
 26                     <Route exact path='/' element={<PostList />} />
 27                     <Route path='/post/:id' element={<Post />} />
 28                 </Routes>
 29             </div>
 30         );
 31     }
 32 }
 33
 34 export default App;
```

index.js

```
  8 ReactDOM.render(
  9     <React.StrictMode>
 10         <HashRouter>
 11             <App />
 12         </HashRouter>
 13     </React.StrictMode>,
 14     document.getElementById('root')
 15 );
```

Comment: What are the props you're passing to `Post`?

Comment: updated post, trying to get the ID parameter from the URL

Comment: Are you using React Router? How did you wrap your app with the Router?

Comment: updated to add more code

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps, you're using react-router-dom at version 6.

Then, utilize useParams, code is like this.

route:

```
<Route path="invoices" element={<Invoices />}>
  <Route path=":invoiceId" element={<Invoice />} />
</Route>
```

path=":invoiceId" : thinks url 'http://site/..../invoices/123'

link:

This makes a path navigating.

```
   <Link
        style={{ display: "block", margin: "1rem 0" }}
        to={`/invoices/${invoice.number}`}
        key={invoice.number}
      >
        {invoice.name}
      </Link>
```

use:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Invoice() {
  let params = useParams();
  return <h2>Invoice: {params.invoiceId}</h2>;
}
```

Please visit here and learn more.
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#reading-url-params

Be helpful for you, I'm glad too.

Answer (score 2):

Please use withRouter.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

....


export default withRouter(Post)
```

Comment: I don't think that is available in the latest version of Router...   export 'withRouter' (imported as 'withRouter') was not found in 'react-router-dom'

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may be using version 6 of `react-router-dom` (latest version as of now)

You can use a hook, called  `useParams()`

Checkout below link to get more details

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams

Comment: Thanks,, but... React Hook "useParams" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: Yes
Thats a limitation possibly
If its quick then you should possibly switch to functional components as the latest react router packages are providing more support for hooks pattern
Or the other way is to downgrade to react router v5.

There can be other patterns also that you can try,
Like making a higher order functional component, getting params from there and passing to your class based components but it needs to be checked if that would work or not.
And it can also increase a bit of complexity

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is at `<Route path='/post/:id' element={<Post />} />`

Have you tried using `component` tag instead? Something like below

```js
<Route path='/post/:id' component={Post} />
```

Comment: This seems to be a step in the right direction, as React no longer errors out.  But my Post component doesn't render, and I get a console warning... Matched leaf route at location "/post/5" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.

Comment: @anonsayshello: I'm sorry but I don't see `Outlet` in the given code above. I think you should do a `console.log(this.props.match.params.id)` at `componentDidMount` in `post-detail.js` and see if you can access `this.props.match.params.id`. If you can get the value, that means the problem is at other place, and has nothing to do with react router anymore?

Comment: Thanks, I tried this. match isn't defined on this.props

Answer (score 1):

> This should be an easy one.

No, not really.  Not when you are trying to apply a tool intended for one paradigm to an entirely different paradigm.

From React Router's upgrade guide "Upgrading from v5":

> In general, React Router v5.1 (and v6) favors elements over components (or "element types").

And even more so in v6, I assume.  The new `<Route>` attribute in v6, after all, is called `element` (and `component` and `render` are dead).

Thus, the correct answer has already been given in Muhammad's comment here: [React this.props.match is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70585815/react-this-props-match-is-undefined#comment124780581_70587067)

Or, to reiterate, if you want to continue using class-based components, either (a) use the version of the tool intended for it (thus, v5.x and not v6) or (b) build your own wrapper function in v6 to pass in in the props.

### React Router 5

The correct answer for v5.x has already been given by a few others here, which is:

```jsx
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

...

export default withRouter(Post)
```

Looking through my old code that hasn't evolved from class-based components yet, I see I'm currently using three solutions/hacks with React Router v5.2:

1. The proper `withRouter()` solution.
2. A hack like:

   1. `<Route path='/post/:id' render={({match}) => (<Post match={match} /> )} />`
   2. Like above but actually implemented with `React.cloneElement()` as the wrapper function.
3. Itemizing the hack like so: `<Route path='/post/:id' render={({match}) => (<Post postId={match.params.id} /> )} />`

Keep in mind this was just to lessen the pain on a large-but-low-budget project while upgrading from React Router v2.0 to v5.2.  When, really, more refactoring should be done to move all components to elements and do it the new way.

### React Router 6

See the v6 FAQ for more details:
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/faq

At the top of that FAQ they've written that wrapper function for us (assuming React 16.8+) and conveniently called it `withRouter()`:

```jsx
import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}
```

This, I assume, is used just like the v5 `withRouter()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify you code follow below code:

import { withRouter } from "react-router";

export default withRouter(Post)